# Octave how to limit boxplot width

Tags: octave, boxplot

I am trying to create a box plot in octave, which also works. But the boxplot is no a square but rather fills the whole plot.

[image]

Is it possible to limit the width of the boxplot?

```
correction = [0.0000000;
   0.0000000;
   0.0000000;
   0.0000000;
   0.0000000;
   0.0000000;
   0.0000000;
   0.0000000;
   0.0052525;
   0.0024731;
   0.0007955;
   0.0040786;
  -0.0007142;
  -0.0006183;
   0.0018019;
   0.0018978;
   0.0013946];

boxplot(correction)
set(gca (), "xtick", [1], "xticklabel", {"correction"})
```

Comment: Please always mention the used version and OS. You should also try to create a MCVE. In your case we havent access to log.txt, but you can rewrite your code to use `rand`

Comment: @Andy I use Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS with Octave 4.2.2

Comment: set (gca, "xlim", [0 2])` would be a workaround